# Export Linq query result to excel EPPLUS

Tags: c#, excel, linq, epplus

I have developed a program to get the Linq query and write it to excel file using EPPLUS (the below code) but it is slow because it is filling the file line by line. is there anyway to fill the excel file all at once? to export all the query at once to excel file?

`fnctnData` is the query result

```
public Boolean GenerateExcel(IEnumerable<ReportData> fnctnData,string fileName,ReportFilTer smf)
        {
            Boolean ret=false;
            try
            {
                string temp = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(temp);
                string templateFile = Path.Combine(di.Parent.FullName, @"templates\Report.xlsx");
                FileInfo itemplateFile = new FileInfo(templateFile);
                FileInfo ReportFile = new FileInfo(fileName);

                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ReportFile,itemplateFile))
                {

                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
                   
                    
                    int i = 5;
                    foreach (var item in fnctnData)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells["A" + i].Value = item.a;
                        worksheet.Cells["B" + i].Value = item.c;
                        worksheet.Cells["C" + i].Value = item.d;
                        worksheet.Cells["D" + i].Value = string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss}", item.Date);
                        worksheet.Cells["E" + i].Value = item.e;
                        worksheet.Cells["F" + i].Value = item.f;
                        worksheet.Cells["G" + i].Value = item.g;
                        i++;
                    }
                    package.SaveAs(ReportFile);
                    ret = true;
                }
            }   
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LibraryLogger.LoggerSoftwareUtility.Error(string.Format("GenerateExcel Exception : {0}", ex));
                throw ex;
            }
            return ret;
            
        }
```

Comment: How much data are you writing?  Its not unusal for the process to be slow with EPPlus.  Did you set break points to see where the bottleneck is?  Probably on the `.SaveAs` line- in which case there is not much you can do.

Comment: not a lot less than 100 rows but it's so slow

Comment: And which line is the actual bottleneck?

Comment: Are you sure fnctnData is not an IQueryable so that your hitting the database on every loop? As Ernie said, what line is slow? If you start off by doing fnctnData = fnctnData.ToList(), does the code execute faster?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to export any arbitrary list into an excel sheet. It accepts the list, a sheet name (so that the excel tab as a specific name.)

the `var header` declaration is only for styling purposes and doesn't have any impact on the actual output. So all `header` related lines can be removed if not needed.

The core of the method is `worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection` which is able to load all list data into excel sheet automatically.

Note that the class should be flat (shouldn't have any nested class objects inside the class), otherwise any complex object will be printed as `<ClassName>` string (instead of actual contents of the complex object.)

```
    public async Task<byte[]> Export<T>(List<T> list, string sheetName) // Sheet Name Example: Device List
    {
        using var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        using ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(memStream);
        var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheetName);

        worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(list, true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Light20);
        worksheet.DefaultColWidth = 25;
        var header = worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, worksheet.Dimension.End.Column];
        header.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        header.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        header.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(0, 75, 101));
        header.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.White);
        worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

        return excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
    }
```