# Exporting Repeater Data to Excel in C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have to Provide the functionality to export all the data shown in repeater to excel file. I have successfully done that but the file size goes above 4MBs.

Here is the code I am using.

```
public void ExportToExcel(Repeater name)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=RepeaterExport.csv");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Repeater rp = name;
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    foreach (RepeaterItem item in name.Items)
    {
        item.Controls.Remove(item.FindControl("hd_Depot"));
        item.Controls.Remove(item.FindControl("hd_ProdCode"));
        item.Controls.Remove(item.FindControl("hd_Closing"));
        item.Controls.Remove(item.FindControl("hd_groupName"));

    }
    rp.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Now when I use xls or xlsx it downloads perfectly but with large size but if I use csv it writes the whole html code to excel file. my main motive here is to shrink the size of the excel file to less than 1MB. Please advise.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403137/export-linq-query-result-to-excel-epplus) shows how to create a real Excel file from a DataTable by calling the LoadFromDataTable method of the [EPPlus] library. EPPlus also has a LoadFromCollection method that can load arbitrary objects. Instead of using a Repeater, use an actual DataTable or list of data objects and pass it to EPPlus

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you write an HTML or CSV file and pretends it is an Excel sheet in the Content-Type so that it opens with Excel. A better solution is to create a real Excel sheet, i.e. with an xlsx extension, using [some](http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/) [library](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) that can do this for you.

Comment: Yes. `xlsx` is a binary format that's already zipped. The original code creates an uncompressed HTML file with a modified extension, hence it's much larger. Despite the extension, the HTML file may or may not be readable by Excel, or lead to localization problems. As far as Excel is concerned, this is only a text file to import using the *default* import settings

Answer (score 0):

I think the xlsx contains the entire html, and that's why it's so big.

If you just want to export to csv:

- create a string which contains the data (in your for loop)
- Contenttype is: "text/csv"

I use a kbCSV and the CSVWriter.

Comment: `xlsx` files are compressed. There is no `xlsx` file involved here - it *is* an HTML file with a `csv` extension and an Excel content type. Creating an actual  `csv` will reduce the size a bit but still won't produce a real  Excel file.